# Window resize should not effect print screen content in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a print button that prints the window content in angular 8, when I resize the window, the content in the print window is also resizing, but I don't want that to get affected. I tried the following ways but nothing seems to be working,

```
1. @media print{
.divName{
zoom: 1;
}
}

2. @media print{
.divName{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Is there any way so that I can achieve what I need, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your css rules need to include the keyword **only**. Try more specific media queries like:

```
  @media only screen { ... }
  @media only print { ... }
```